# Помгите найти элемент selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Пишу программу на selenium всё шло хорошо, но я столкнулся с элементом у которого я копирую XPath - не работает, CSS_SELECTOR - не работает, ID - не работает. Может я делал что-то не так. Буду рад помощи.

Развёртка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: нужный элемент я выделил
экран 1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экран 2:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Экран 3:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если не получится - напишите, возможно на момент загрузки страницы этого элемента нет вовсе...тогда можно будет попробовать добавить явное ожидание

Comment: плюс возможно данный элемент появляется после каких-то ваших действий...может поделитесь ссылкой на тестируемую страницу(если она публичная конечно)

Comment: не работает, страницу скинуть не могу поскольку приватная, но смысл примерно как в дзене когда пишешь новую статью. Есть заголовок на него нажимаешь и пишешь, а снизу нужно нажать и вводить сам текст. Заголовок у меня получается, а вот текст нет.

Comment: сделайте несколько скриншотов страницы 1 сразу после загрузки, 2 после того как ткнули в заголовок, 3 после того как ткнули в текст

Comment: Добавил в той же последовательности

Comment: понятно...я после 4 освобожусь и отвечу (раньше не смогу)

Comment: буду благодарен

Comment: я про вас не забыл если что...я даже себе wordpress развернул...так классы правда немного другие(версии отличаются по всей видмсомти)... но поведение воспроизводится.

Comment: там я уперся в то, что весь этот редактор лежит в iframe... и я полагаю с этим все и связано.я попытаюсь через него решить эту задачку и вам отписаться

Comment: спасибо большое. Возможно вы зашли на Wordpress.com. Поскольку сделать  запись на Wordpress.org (которым я пользуюсь) можно только после оплаты хостинга

Comment: О.. Во как... Спасибо за информацию

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но я решил. Я сделал так что вместо обычного поля для ввода, я выбираю поле для ввода HTML (что мне кстати) и там элемент нажимается без проблем.

Comment: спасибо, что предупредили - я как раз собирался за ваш вопрос снова садиться

Answer (score 0):

в CSS селекторе не всегда нужно выбирать все элементы
Иногда нужно отделять зерна от плевел и оставлять только самое важное

попробуйте так:

```
div.block-editor-block-list__layout p.block-editor-block-list__block
```

**В итоге:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.your.site/")

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.block-editor-block-list__layout p.block-editor-block-list__block")

element.click()
element.send_keys("Hello from Selenium!")
```